# Custom directive (on Class) inside ng-repeat never evaluated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview

In Angular (1.2) I'm printing out some `li` elements using ng-repeat and I conditionally apply to them a class with `ng-class`.

```
 <li ng-repeat="(linkName, link) in navigation" ng-class="{'treeview':condition}">
    <a href ng-if="link.state" ui-sref="{{link.state}}">
        <i class="fa {{link.icon}}"></i>
        <span>{{linkName}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The class `treeview` that depends on the `condition` represents a custom directive that I've defined:

```
angular.module('app.mymodule')
.directive('treeview', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // jquery tree plugin 
            element.tree();
        }
    };
})
```

This should enable the jquery **tree** plugin on the elements having a `treeview` class.
The problem is that even tough the elements are correctly added to the dom and have a class `treeview` the custom directive `treeview` is never evaluated (verified this with a breakpoint).

Instead, if I do a plain

```
<li class="treeview">
    //...
</li>
```

Then the directive works as supposed to do.
I think it is some sort of conflict over the scope created by ng-repeat..

Answer (score 0):

## Transclude

In your directive set transclude to true. That lets you evaluate things between custom tags.